# Budgie-panel crashes periodically

Tags: 18.04, gtk, crash, budgie

Running Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 LTS.
budgie-panel crashes every 30 minutes or so.
This is the error message:

```
(budgie-panel:30012): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 20:47:56.014: gtk_widget_add_accelerator: assertion 'GTK_IS_ACCEL_GROUP (accel_group)' failed
```

If someone can interpret this for me, or offer a solution, that would be great.
Thanks, all.

Comment: Did you add any 3rd party applets? (Or any at all). Also: does the panel freeze, or crash and disappear?

Comment: I haven't added any since upgrading. It hasn't had this problem in the previous year that I've used Budgie.

Comment: Please try and reset the panel: `nohup budgie-panel --reset -- replace &`. Possibly things got corrupted in the update.

Comment: I’ve tried both many times

Comment: Hmmm, did you also try resetting via dconf directly?

Comment: Nope. How do I do that?

Comment: `dconf reset -f /com/solus-project/budgie-panel/`. Directly after that, your panel will look messed up, but after a log out/in, it will be in the state of a fresh install.

Comment: ^ just curious, but did you try?